# C# Different probabilities in if statements

Tags: c#, math, probability

I am writing a program where I put different students in different classrooms. I'm having some trouble figuring out how to use probabilities in C#, and programming in general. I want it to be a 5% probability to become a student in Alpha, 10& for Omega & 60% for Nightwalkers. I don't understand what numbers to put in.My method right now:

```
    public string AssignClassroom()
    {
        int rand = random.Next(0, 100);
        {
            if (rand < 5) // or >95%?
            {
                student.Classroom = "Alpha";
            }

            if (rand < 10) // or >90?
            {
                student.Classroom = "Omega";
            }

            if (rand < 60) // or >40?
            {
                student.Classroom = "Nightwalkers";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Put `else` between statements.

Comment: @RoyiNamir Fixed it. So the rest looks right? I can do it this way? What I'm thinking is, say rand = 96. Then the student won't be assigned to any classroom..

Comment: So, your desired probabilities add up to 75%. What's meant to happen to the other 25% of students? That's a maths problem, not a programming one.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I assume I shouldn't slump (0,100)?

Comment: In a real world, you should probably split on the count of students. Your algorithm (even if it's fixed) will put students with a certain _probability_ into certain rooms. Since there's no guarantee that the random numbers will be evently distributed, you could still end up squeezing all into room Alpha.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should *add up* figures in `if`s:

```
        if (rand < 5)             {
            student.Classroom = "Alpha";
        }
        else if (rand < 10 + 5) 
        {
            student.Classroom = "Omega";
        }
        else if (rand < 60 + 10 + 5) 
        {
            student.Classroom = "Nightwalkers";
        }
```

Note, that `5, 10, 60` are differencies:

```
  0  .. 5  .. 15 .. 75
  |  5  |     |     |  ->  5% top students go to the 1st class 
        | 10  |     |  -> 10% next go to the 2nd 
              | 60  |  -> 60% goes to the 3d
```